# How to create multiple Kafka clusters on same L2 network?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have 12 Kafka nodes on same L2 Network.

I want to create 4 Kafka clusters (each with 3 nodes) on same L2 network.

Is it possible to do this and how?
If not then what's the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Kafka cluster is basically defined by the Zookeeper data model that its members use. So, if you want some brokers to belong to a given cluster, you have to make them point to the same Zookeeper namespace. In practical terms, if you want to have 4 clusters then you will need 4 different chroots in your Zookeeper ensemble and make each cluster use a different one. For example, members of cluster A will use **zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181/cluster/a**, members of cluster B will use **zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181/cluster/b** and so on. Of course another alternative is to use a completely separated Zookeeper ensembles for each cluster.

From [ZooKeeper Programmer's Guide](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkSessions)

> An optional "chroot" suffix may also be appended to the connection
>   string. This will run the client commands while interpreting all paths
>   relative to this root (similar to the unix chroot command). If used
>   the example would look like: "127.0.0.1:4545/app/a" or
>   "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002/app/a" where the client
>   would be rooted at "/app/a" and all paths would be relative to this
>   root - ie getting/setting/etc... "/foo/bar" would result in operations
>   being run on "/app/a/foo/bar" (from the server perspective). This
>   feature is particularly useful in multi-tenant environments where each
>   user of a particular ZooKeeper service could be rooted differently.
>   This makes re-use much simpler as each user can code his/her
>   application as if it were rooted at "/", while actual location (say
>   /app/a) could be determined at deployment time.